# IE Handling in Excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel macros and I am trying to auto-fill the text box and select the option from Dropdown and click on Submit.

Using macros I have navigated to a page and from the page, I need to enter the text in the text box, and based on the Suggestion, I need to select the option.

Once the option is selected I need to click on continue using macros.

Here is the current code (I tried with the commented line but it's not working).

```
Sub Create_Change()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object
    Dim HWNDSrc As Long
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    URL = "URL to Navigate"
    IE.Navigate URL
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"
    ' IE.Document.All("Search for a template").Value = "text to search"
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing
End Sub
```

HTML CODE:

```html
<input title="Search for a template" 
       class="change-template__search-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" 
       role="combobox" 
       aria-expanded="false" 
       aria-owns="typeahead-258-8737" 
       aria-autocomplete="list" 
       type="text" 
       placeholder="Search for a template" 
       ng-enter="getRecommendedTemplates(template.search)" 
       ng-model="template.search" 
       typeahead="template as template for template in getTemplateList($viewValue)" 
       typeahead-focus-first="false" 
       typeahead-on-select="getRecommendedTemplates($item)" 
       typeahead-min-length="3">
```

Comment: Is there an url we can test with?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to search through all the elements returned by Document.All().  Try looping through the collection that is returned.  This is much easier if the control had an id, but you will have to check each element having a title = "Search for a template".  Once you have found the item you can set the text.

I suggest debugging so you can see what .All returns and then you can work from there.

Comment: Thanks for your respone drHodge.I tried to add below line as mentioned by Mariano, but the text is not filling

 For Each Item In IE.Document.all()
    If Item.getAttribute("title") = "Search for a template" Then
    Item.Value = "ORADB"
    End If
    Next Item

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO. If you need to get an element, as drHodge said, using an iterator and some sort of ID attribute is usually enough. I tried this with Google a minute ago:

```
Dim Item As Object
For Each Item In IE.Document.all()
If Item.getAttribute("title") = "Buscar" Then
Item.Value = "Test"
End If
Next Item
```

I also made it press space, down arrow and enter, for the sake of doing something with the suggestion and searching part:

```
SendKeys ("{ }")
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys ("{DOWN}"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
SendKeys ("{ENTER}"), True
```

(I do not recommend using SendKeys on any script, tho; it's quite unreliable.)

Comment: Thanks for your respone Mariano.I tried to add below line as mentioned by  but the text is not filling

 For Each Item In IE.Document.all()
    If Item.getAttribute("title") = "Search for a template" Then
    Item.Value = "ORADB"
    End If
    Next Item

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hi Philbin. Is this HTML being downloaded in real-time navigation, or is it a file on your computer? Are you sure that there's actually an element with that title? I just made the same loop with your exact HTML snippet (saved as a file) and got it working; that's why I'm guessing something changed on the HTML you're searching in. Here's the whole Sub: https://codeshare.io/5zkL8r
Note that this isn't production code: it could fail in several ways and it isn't as efficient as it could.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1) Focus and change

```
With ie.document.querySelector("[title='Search for a template']")
    .focus
    .value = "abcd"
End With
```

2) Javascript set value

```
ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('[title=\'Search for a template\']').value = 'abcd';"
```

3) Attach event and fire

```
Dim evt As Object
Set evt = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "change", True, False

With ie.document.querySelector("[title='Search for a template']")
    .Focus
    .Value = "abcd"
    .dispatchEvent evt
End With
```

4) FireEvent

```
With ie.document.querySelector("[title='Search for a template']")
    .Focus
    .Value = "abcd"
    .FireEvent "onchange"
End With
```