# how to click HTML innertext with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, automation

how to click inner-text of "li" through VBA? rhef is dynamic.
i have 3 pages,, when form is loaded,, page is by default 1,,I have to click no 2 page.
i have pasted the below code,, when i see with step by step, line is going through loop, and pass the line "difHTMLA.Click" but neither it is throwing error nor reload the page. PLEASE HELP

```
Set difHTMLAs = doc.getElementsByTagName("li")
    For Each difHTMLA In difHTMLAs
        If difHTMLA.getAttribute("classname") = "swfPagingOtherPageArea swf-left" Then
            If CStr(Trim(difHTMLA.innerText)) = "2" Then
            difHTMLA.Click
            End If
        End If
      Next difHTMLA
    Exit For
```

```html
<ul class="swfPaging">    
        <li> 
          &lt;
        </li>  
            <li class="swfPagingSelectedPageArea swf-left">
              1
            </li>
            <li class="swfPagingOtherPageArea swf-left">       
              <a href="/wps/myportal/dynamic URL/">
                2
              </a>
            </li>    
            <li class="swfPagingOtherPageArea swf-left">
              <a href="/wps/myportal/dynamic URL/">
                3
              </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: Again a question without any link to a website. You are asking a question related to web-scraping but there is no site to play with. This mostly happens in vba questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css `:nth-of-type` pseudo selector to target the class of the parent `li`. Css selectors are applied via querySelector to return first match or querySelectorAll to return all matches. You then want the child [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tag within the `li` with class `swfPagingOtherPageArea`. The `.` in front, below, is a css class selector. It selects elements based on their class attribute name. This is based on html supplied.

```
ie.document.querySelector(".swfPagingOtherPageArea:nth-of-type(3) a")
```

page 2

or

```
ie.document.querySelector(".swfPagingOtherPageArea:nth-of-type(4) a")
```

page 3

That is from start page.

Without seeing the page it is more difficult to advise on looping pages as elements may change. For example, you may find that when on page two you cannot use `.swfPagingOtherPageArea:nth-of-type(4) a` to get page 3 as page 3 is now `.swfPagingOtherPageArea:nth-of-type(3) a` i.e. The class name of the active page changes and thus the correct index to use changes.

---

If that is still not triggering then you may need to FireEvent "onclick" on the element

```
ie.document.querySelector(".swfPagingOtherPageArea:nth-of-type(3) a").FireEvent "onclick"
```

If that still fails you can try adding an event to the node as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56356248/6241235)